# php.ini cli symbolic link

Tags: php, administration

Why do we have a different php.ini for the php client ?

Is it a good idea to link the main instead ?

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It entirely up to you how you configure your system, based on your needs. However, there are good reasons for having separate configuration files for CLI and Apache, not least because a web server is typically an externally facing service. For example:

- Disabling some extensions to minimise security risks.
- Configuring lower memory limits to limit the potential for denial of service attacks.

Note that you can also configure your PHP installation by adding files to `/etc/php5/conf.d`. This is a good way to keep your customisations in their own file and avoid conflicts in your `php.ini` file(s) if they get updated by a new version of the packages. The latter point is also an issue if you choose to use symlinks for `php.ini`. Note that the `conf.d` directories for `cli` and `apache` are symlinks.